# Oracle VM VirtualBox Ubuntu windowed mode doesn't expand to full screen

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

So my Ubuntu virtual machine is up and running, but it doesn't show expand to the full screen.

[image: the screenshot I made]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Activate VM and sign in.
2. Click on 'Devices' and select 'Insert Guest Additions CD Image'
3. A window will pop up in the VM asking if you want to start some software. Select Run.
4. Enter in your password.
5. A terminal window will open and an installation script will activate and automatically run.
6. Partway through, your VM should resize to your screen.
7. The terminal window will say that the system is not set up to build kernel modules.
8. You can simply hit Enter when it says press return to close this window.
9. Now, whenever you resize your window, The VM will automatically resize itself.

Comment: Thank you for such clear instructions, everything works fine now :)

Answer (score -1):

Click on View and go to full-screen mode.

Comment: This only works if you have the Guest Additions installed per the other answer here, which allows the Hypervisor window size to be communicated to the VM in a way that can trigger the resize.